# How to get and use table in html by javascript by getElementsByClassName()?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-chrome-extension

I want to detect an element in a table in HTML, but I can find the table in html(I think), I cannot detect the table...PS: I can not change the HTML.

This is DOM

[image]

This is my code

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt'));
```

I can get alert like
[image]

after, I want to detect the table or use the table, but i can't..
I use the table like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt').rows
```

and my programme crashes, it can not find rows.....

In the html like I have posted, How to get and use table html? Could you give me some code? Thank you !

Comment: "*This is HTML*" - no it isn't; that's a picture of the DOM. Please add your ("[*MCVE*]") HTML to your question.

Comment: I feel there are way to many answers to this simple question...I'm counting myself out.

Comment: but for now. none of them works...

Answer (score 3):

First `getElementsByClassName` method returns an `HTMLCollection` or `NodeList` so to get the table you have to get the element from returned collection like this

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')[0];
```

And then you can get and iterate through rows of table element, something like this

```
for (var i = 0;i < table.rows.length; i++) {
     var row = table.rows[i];

}
```

Comment: It's best to call it "array-like" because an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) doesn't have any of the methods from `Array.prototype`

Answer (score 2):

For increased compatibility (IE 8, for example, does not support `getElementsByClassName()` whereas it does support `querySelector()`) I'd suggest using `document.querySelector()`, which will return the only first matching Node – rather than a NodeList – matching a supplied CSS selector:

```
var table = document.querySelector('.ep-dp-dt'),
    rows = table.rows;
```

The above will first retrieve the `<table>` element (assuming it both exists and is the first element in the document matching the `.ep-dp-dt` selector) and then use that Node to retrieve the collection of `<tr>` elements and store them in the `rows` variable.

Obviously to work with the `<tr>` elements you'll need to iterate over the collection, using either a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i<len; i++){
    console.log(rows[i]);
}
```

Or you could instead use Array methods, if you first convert the Array-like `HTMLCollection` into an Array using `Array.from()`:

```
Array.from( rows ).forEach(function(tr) {
    console.log(tr);
});
```

Or, as Array.from() is from ES6, and you may need to support older browsers the following alternative is possible:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(rows, 0).forEach(function(tr) {
    console.log(tr);
});
```

It's worth noting, at this point, that while `document.querySelector()` will return the first node matching the given selector it will, if no element matching that selector is found within the document, return `null`; which means that it may be worth testing for the existence of the `table` variable before attempting to retrieve the `rows` collection:

```
var table = document.querySelector('.ep-dp-dt'),
    rows;

if (table) {
    rows = table.rows;
}
```

Comment: I got `exceptionHandler.handle('Error in event handler for ' +(this.eventName ? this.eventName : '(unknown)'),e);`

Comment: [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is from EMCAScript6, so it isn't supported by IE or Opera.

Comment: @4castle: indeed; I've updated with an alternative for older browsers. user2262304: I don't see any mention of that code in your question. You may wish to provide a more full sample of your code to better explain what you're trying to do when you run that code.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, having that class. Either give element an id and use `getElementById()` or if you are sure, that only one element has the class, use `document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')[0]`

Comment: I can not change HTML, and I am sure only one element has the class

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array of elements. To select the first element, you need to add `[0]`, like so:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')[0]
```

Then to get the rows, try one of the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')[0].rows
document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')
```

You'll get an array of each row.

Comment: I have test `alert(document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')[0].rows);` and it doesn't work, the programme crashes

Comment: why do you use alert? try `console.log()` and open the developer tools (F12 in chrome) to see what is logged

Comment: What'd you get if you `console.log` each of the following: `document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')`, `document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')[0]`, `document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')`

Comment: it crashes `{return InjectedScript.primitiveTypes[typeof object]&&!this._isHTMLAllCollection(object);},wrapObject:function(object,groupName,canAccessInspectedGlobalObject,generatePreview)
{if(canAccessInspectedGlobalObject)`

Comment: Run it in incognito mode, this should not be happening.

Comment: Chrome - https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7005900?hl=en&rd=1; Safari - https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19216?locale=en_US; Firefox - https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/private-browsing/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, after `alert(document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt'));`, I got htmlcollection not tableoject, it is normal or not ?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` will return array of elements even if it's one element in page. You must select desired index of class (in your case it would be 0)

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('ep-dp-dt')[0].rows);
```

```html
<table class="ep-dp-dt">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get `Error in event handler for tabs.onUpdated: TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined`